# Using jq to select value from multiple datatypes (array/object)

Tags: sh, jq

I have a curl cmd and return either one of json structure as below

#1

```
{
    "keys": [
      {
        "key": "1234567890"
      }
    ]
}
```

#2

```
{
    "keys": [
      "1234567890"
    ]
}
```

Shell/bash script (Mac)

```
key=$(curl "blah blah blah" | jq '??????')
```

what would be ????? look like to get the key by either one of json structure

billion thanks

Comment: The first response isn't valid JSON, there's a stray comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to do an explicit check of the type of the content within `keys` as

```
.keys[] | if type == "string" then . elif type == "object" then .key else empty end
```

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4YR9Kq1eggz)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Destructuring Alternative Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#DestructuringAlternativeOperator%3A%3F%2F%2F) `?//`:

```bash
.keys as [{$key}] ?// [$key] | $key
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RbcOV-NVUhg)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a further alternative as a mixture of the conciseness of @pmf's solution and the readability of @inian's solution (both great approaches):

```
.[].keys|first|(.key? // .)
```